# Postgres Servlet error: operator does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have an sql statement that I previously thought was working, but is now throwing an error I haven't encountered before. I can't tell what is wrong with my sql statement, so I'm here hoping an extra set of eyes might be able to tell me whats wrong. The error I'm getting is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean ~~ character varying
>   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Position: 78`

Here is my code snippet, I'm pretty sure the problem is in here somewhere:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM books LEFT JOIN book_tags ON (books.isbn_13=book_tags.isbn_13) LIKE ?";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "%" + tag.getIsbn_13() + "%");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); //line 78
```

Comment: What is `(books.isbn_13=book_tags.isbn_13) LIKE ?` supposed to do in the JOIN condition? `books.isbn_13=book_tags.isbn_13` is a comparison which results in a boolean value, you can't use LIKE with a boolean. Do you mean to join on `books.isbn_13=book_tags.isbn_13` and then do a `books.isbn_13 like ?` in the WHERE clause perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I'm joining the two tables on match isbn_13. Are you saying in order to use the like I need to use a where clause?

Comment: Probably yes. BTW, `~~` is the same as the LIKE operator, hence the error message.

Comment: `(books.isbn_13=book_tags.isbn_13) LIKE ?` makes no sense at all this is essentially the same as `(true) LIKE ?` What is the `LIKE` intended to do? On which _column_ from which table do you want to apply the `LIKE` operator?